Codecommit - cannot create a repository
Why am I unable to create a repository in CodeCommit?
when I am creating a new repository in AWS codecommit it's throwing this error...
"Create Repository request is not allowed because there is no existing repository in this AWS account or AWS Organization"
Is there any alternate way to use codecommit as a new user in codecommit?

AWS has discontinued CodeCommit. If your account wasn't already using it, they won't let you start using it. Read the first paragraph here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/how-to-migrate-your-aws-codecommit-repository-to-another-git-provider/
